# In Swift, is it possible to use a parameter value in a default parameter value?

Tags: swift

I wanna do something like that:

```
func test(parameter1: Class1, parameter2: Class2 = Class2(class1: parameter1)) {

  }
```

Is there any way for doing that in Swift?

Comment: The standard technique is to have it be `parameter2: Class2? = nil`, and then inside the code have some local var that is `let object2 = parameter2 ?? Class2(class1: parameter1)`.

Comment: Did you try this? Is there any particular error?

Comment: @Kamran, default value has no access to the parameters' names, so you can't refer to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the second parameter an Optional with a nil default, and do what you are doing in the body of the function if it is in fact nil.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, but you can make `parameter2` optional and do something like this:

```
func test(parameter1: Class1, parameter2: Class2? = nil) {
    let param2 = parameter2 ?? Class2(class1: parameter1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible yet

but you can use the optional option as Rob says.

I tried this in a playground:

```
class Class1 {
    var name = ""
}

class Class2 {
    var class1:Class1?
    init(class1: Class1) {
        self.class1 = class1
    }

    func printNameClass1() {
        print(class1?.name ?? "No name")
    }
}

func test(parameter1: Class1, parameter2: Class2? = nil ) {

    parameter1.name = "Camilo"

    let object2 = parameter2 ?? Class2(class1: parameter1)
    object2.printNameClass1()
}

let param1 = Class1()

test(parameter1: param1)
```